# TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I`m trying to download and then open excel file (report) generated by marketplace with openpyxl.

```
import requests
import config
import openpyxl

link = 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' + config.TOKEN + '/documents/file_66.xlsx'

def save_open(link):
    
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(link)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(r.content)

    wb = openpyxl.open ('file_66.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    cell = ws['B2'].value
    print (cell)

save_open(link)
```

After running this code I got the above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\Documents\myPython\bot_WB\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    save_open(link)
  File "C:\Users\Home\Documents\myPython\bot_WB\main.py", line 14, in save_open
    wb = openpyxl.open ('file_66.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.fills = fills
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
[Finished in 1.6s]
```

If you run file properties/details you can see that this file was generated by "Go Exelize" (author: xuri). To run this file you need to separate code in two parts. First: download file. Then you need to manually open it with MS Excel, save file and close it (after this "Go Excelize" switch to "Microsoft Excel"). And only after that you can run the second part of the code correctly with no errors. Can anyone help me to handle this problem?

Comment: The exception tells you that the file is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, **"TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))"**, using pandas.read_excel, which uses openpyxl. If I open the file, save and close it, it will work with both, pandas and openpyxl.

Upon further attempts I could open the file using the "read_only=True" in openpyxl, but while iterating over the rows I would still get the error, but only when all the rows ended, in the end of the file.

I belive it could be something in the EOF (end of file) and openpyxl don't have ways of treating it.

Here is the code that I used to test and worked for me:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(my_file_name, read_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
lis = []
try:
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        lis.append([cell.value for cell in row])
except TypeError:
    print('Skip error in EOF')
```

Used openpyxl==3.0.10

Answer (score 0):

I think EOF is related with this problem.
After reading Rodolfo'comment, I deleted the end of rows in my excel file by my hand and it worked it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35194966)