# Python convert multiple .xlsx to .csv: TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Tags: python, csv, xlsx

I have multiple LabVIEW-generated .xlsx files in one folder, which I wish to convert to .csv.

I have tried different ways, but all throw the same error:

> TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from glob import glob

for xslx_file in glob(r"C:\path...\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(xslx_file)
    csv_file = os.path.splitext(xslx_file)[0] + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=None, header=True)
```

After reviewing the [following question](https://groups.google.com/g/openpyxl-users/c/353l1x10tCY) I thought the TypeError might indicate there is something wrong with the files generated by LabVIEW so I tried converting just one of the files from the same folder, but this worked fine. Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\path...\file.xlsx")
df.to_csv(r"C:\path...\file.csv", sep=",")
```

I also reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557551/typeerror-expected-class-openpyxl-styles-fills-fill) but was not able to transfer anything useful from the solution to my problem.

My question is, therefore, how can I loop the conversion over all files in the specified directory?

Comment: Is the file your checking w/o loop (e.g. file.xlsx) the same file that is causing the error? Is TypeError caused by the first file it handles?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Good question, but yes it is the same file. I tested the individual file conversion on the first file in the folder so it is the same as the first file handled by the loop --- so it works without the loop but not with it.

Comment: Is the error on read_excel() or to_csv() line ? Also, did you call df.to_csv() with same arguments as in loop - example above has sep=',' vs index=None, etc.

Comment: @CodeMonkey 1) I have tried all variations of those arguments. 2) The full traceback indicates the error is on the read_excel line. If I remove the \ before the * in the For... line, the TypeError disappears and the code runs but it does not do anything to the .xlsx files in the folder.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example of an Excel file that that throws a TypeError would help otherwise any solution is just guess work. Does the excel workbook have multiple sheets vs single sheet, simple formatting vs complex with charts, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl` supports newer Excel file formats.

Try `engine='openpyxl'`.

```
for xslx_file in glob(r"C:\path...\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(xslx_file, engine='openpyxl') # <== updated
    csv_file = os.path.splitext(xslx_file)[0] + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=None, header=True)
```

For debugging, add `verbose=True` to `pd.read_excel()`.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution still throws the same error. :(  *TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments*, which is followed by *During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:* ...... *TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>*. I have also verified that openpyxl is installed and have tried switching the \ to /. Do you have any other ideas, please?

Comment: If you run code w/o loop *df = pd.read_excel(...); df.to_csv("...file.csv", sep=",")* then no error and verified a new CSV file is created with the correct data? Your code works fine with typical Excel files so must be something in the LabVIEW-generated .xlsx files.

Comment: I think you are right that there may be something up with the Labview xlsx files. I have instead implemented a solution using VBA code in a step separate to the rest of my work in Python. Thank you for your time and your input, it is greatly appreciated.